# There is an issue when we upload a PDF file as a BIM Model

Tags: autodesk-forge

I wish you a great year.

PDF issue:
When we upload a pdf as a BIM Model and want to create a ticket (on the top of the right side), the view is crashing and getting smaller and move to the left corner. This issue is affecting of the accurate of the measurement and markups.

Example of the issue:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3borW.png)

Looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Best Regards,

Comment: Please share your issue through the link shared previously. You can also email us through aps[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com